# random sqrt string generation

Tags: java, random

I need to generate 4 numbers between 20 to 100 and to print all of them . after that i need to print and to know who the random number that his sqrt the closet one to the number that my ''man'' chose on the start . I know what I want to do but I didn't succeed.

```
public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println((int)((Math.random() * 81) + 20));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please you may think about accepting an answer now or comment it ;) Or vote up ;)

Answer (score -1):

For each value you need to check the distance with the `sqrt` and keep if if better (for 4 values, use a bound of 4 and not 5 in the loop) :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int choosen = 6; // Use a Scanner to use user input
    double nearestsqrt = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int value, nearest=-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        value = (int)((Math.random() * 81) + 20);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(value);
        if(Math.abs(sqrt-choosen) < Math.abs(nearestsqrt- choosen)){
            nearestsqrt = sqrt;
            nearest = value;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nearest);
}
```